# Moving salesforce org from EU to USA to cut costs

Tags: pricing

My company is UK based, where list price for salesforce licenses is £85. We have a USA office, where the list price is almost half that amount for the exact same service.

We're looking at having our USA operation manage salesforce as it will save a huge amounts every year. Does anyone know a way of migrating a complete organisation (complete with custom objects, workflows, etc) in this way?

Comment: rip off Britain strikes again eh

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing and have a clear plan, I don't suggest trying this on your own. Contact salesforce.com and ask them if they can move you, as this would be the least expensive option. If not, you can expect to hire an expensive consultant to perform the migration. It'll be a large number of hours in most cases, depending on how much data you need to migrate.

Comment: You could try putting your metadata into a package, and moving that over to the new org, and then manually importing your data back in via the dataloader. Would be a lot of time and effort, however.